# Alfred and Spotlight don't detect VSCode even though I've it on shortcuts

Tags: macos, applications, spotlight, alfred

When I installed the VSCode I had added it to dock applications.

I am not able to find it/open it with Alfred or Spotlight. I tried to search for: code, VSCode, visual studio code, and nothing. It seems like if I remove VSCode from dock, I won't be able to start it again.

Any idea?

Comment: It is possible that **1** Spotlight index is incomplete, it will take some time. or **2** The folder with VSC is hidden in Spotlight Preferences -> Privacy. There might be other things too, these are the first two steps, I think.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Have you tried to add the VSCode folders to the Spotlight index manually?

Comment: Spotlight less important for me then Alfred currently. Checked the privacy settings and there's no limitation.

Comment: Have you contacted the developer of that software for help?

Comment: go to system preferences and click on Spotlight. and then click on the tab "search results".  This is where you pick folders to search.  There should be an entry for Applications. make sure it is checked.

Comment: You added it to "dock applications"?  What's that?  Add it to `/Applications`, then create a shortcut on the Dock.  It should work after that.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and just managed to fix it.

I went to System Preferences > Spotlight > Search Results and then unchecked "Applications", then re-checked "Applications" and it instantly fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, turns out VSCode app was in the bin.
I put it back in Applications and Spotlight found it right away.

Comment: where is the bin?

Answer (score 0):

for your secondary issue of `Spotlight Search: VSCode` not finding `Visual Studio Code` the easiest fix is to create an alias

- right click `Visual Studio Code` in `Applications`
- click `Make Alias`
- rename `Visual Studio Code alias` to `VSCode`

`Spotlight Search: VSCode` should immediately begin working as expected